Why are my text in italic?
I'm not entirely sure why my text are in italic in Question 3. Would appreciate any advice on this.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Libraries.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{mathtools}




\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}

% Shortcuts.
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\ti}[1]{\textit{#1}}

% Attr.
\title{Assignment}
\author{Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    % Declaration 

\vfill
    \it{We wish to acknowledge this land on which the University of Toronto operates. For thousands of years it has been the traditional land of the Huron-Wendat, the Seneca, and the Mississaugas of the Credit. Today, this meeting place is still the home to many Indigenous people from across Turtle Island.}\\

    \it{We do not acknowledge the land in hope of justifying settler colonialism or understate the traumatic horror it has brought to the land. Instead, we recognize that the claim of institutions or persons “owning” the land as “private property” is fallacious, and that we are privileged to have the opportunity to work on this land.}\\

    \it{In our work, we strive not only for advancements in our fields of expertise but also for diversity, equity, inclusion, and evolving human rights that we are trying to better understand every day. It is through these efforts that we could have some hope of honoring the land and all that it represents.}

\vfill % Add flexible vertical space after the paragraph
\newpage
\section{Question 1}




    \newpage
\section{Question 2}



    \newpage
\section{Question 3}

Suppose that $\{X_t\}$ is a stationary stochastic process with spectral density function $f_X(\omega)$. We define 
$$Y_t = \sum^\infty_{u=\infty} c_u X_{t-u}$$
$$Z_t = Y_t + \sum^\infty_{u=-\infty}c_u(X_{t-u}-Y_{t-u})$$

    
\end{document}


\it, aside from being not recommended in LaTeX, does not take an argument; it sets everything that follows it in italic.  You want to use \textit to limit the scope.

You declare that text should be in italic shape. So what is the problem? BTW, be aware that in LaTeX document is strongly advised to use LaTeX command and not strange mix of TeX and LaTeX ones. This are kulprits for your troubles.

You can refer to https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes%2C_families%2C_and_styles.  The LaTeX command would be \itshape, but it is a switch, making everything italic until you switch back.

welcome! if you use two-letter switches for fonts (which you shouldn't in latex), you will sometimes get the wrong font because newer kernels make some attempt to combine different aspects of fonts in intuitive ways e.g. compare \textit{\textsc{small-caps italic}} with {\it\sc small-caps italic}. the former will produce the expected result, if the current font supports the shape. the latter will never do so.

instead of or as well as \newcommand{\ti}[1]{\textit{#1}}, you could just say \renewcommand{\it}[1]{\textit{#1}}.it isn't really a mix of tex and latex commands, because latex defines \it - not tex - but I agree with @Zarko that it makes for strange and confusing syntax as this example shows. (that is, you are not getting a tex definition of \it in latex.)

And if you did want to change all following text within the environment to italic in LaTeX, use \itshape rather than \it. The plain TeX commands won’t work as expected.
